# FindMy "People" tab not showing

Tags: ios, family-sharing, find-my

I have upgraded both my iphone and my daughter's (a minor in family sharing) iphone to iOS 15 and now the "People" tab on the FindMy app on my daughter's iphone is not showing and I can't see her location.

Comment: Did you tried to switch iPhone off and on again ?